# Can't display variable

Tags: java, variables, methods

I'm very new to programming and I'm having some trouble displaying the variable monthlyPayment in my main method; I think it has something to do with the previous method. This is a monthly payment calculator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assignment8 {

public static double pow(double a, int b) {
    double ans = 1;
    if (b < 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < -b; i++) {
            ans *= 1/a;
        }
    }
    return ans;
}

public static double monthlyPayment(double amountBorrowed, int loanLength, int percentage) {
    double monthlyPayment;
    double P = amountBorrowed;
    double N = 12 * loanLength;
    double r = (percentage / 100) / 12;
    monthlyPayment = (r * P) / (1 - Math.pow((1 + r) , -N ));
    return monthlyPayment;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the amount borrowed: $");
    double amountBorrowed = kbd.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
    int interestRate = kbd.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the minimum length of the loan: ");
    int minLoanLength = kbd.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the maximum length of the loan: ");
    int maxLoanLength = kbd.nextInt();

    while (maxLoanLength < minLoanLength) {
        System.out.print("Enter the maximum legth og the loan: ");
        maxLoanLength = kbd.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = minLoanLength; i <= maxLoanLength; i++) {

        System.out.println(i + monthlyPayment);
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: 'some trouble displaying the variable' - What kind of trouble is it? Could You be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your `monthlyPayment` method:

```
public static double monthlyPayment(double amountBorrowed, int loanLength, int percentage)
```

It takes 3 arguments and returns a double.

This is how you're calling your `monthlyPayment` method:

```
System.out.println(i + monthlyPayment);
```

You're not sending it any arguments.  You're not even including the `()`.  Your compiler should be complaining.

You need to be doing this instead:

```
System.out.println(i + monthlyPayment(amountBorrowed, loanLength, percentage));
```

Note: You're still probably not going to get your expected results.  This will sum `i` and the result of your call to `monthlyPayment` and then print that.  You may want something like this:

```
System.out.println("Month " + i + " payment: " + monthlyPayment(amountBorrowed, loanLength, percentage));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still getting some errors but I think I can work those out.

Comment: I'd love to know why I've been downvoted.

Comment: I don't think that was me, was it?

Comment: I'm new to this website

Comment: No.  You don't have enough rep to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
monthlyPayment(double amountBorrowed, int loanLength, int percentage)
```

You need to pass the arguments

```
System.out.println(i + monthlyPayment( amountBorrowed, loanLength, percentage));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
System.out.println(i + ": " + monthlyPayment(amountBorrowed, loanLength, percentage));
```

The type of `i` and `monthlyPayment` are int and double. By default the `+` operator for 2 number will return the sum of the 2 number.

You need to convert the number to a string before using the `+`.